# how to differentiate whether the environment is a virtual host or not?

Tags: php, environment-variables, virtualhost, superglobals

I have this code here:

```
$config['SUBFOLDER'] = '/';
$config['APP_URL'] = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$config['SUBFOLDER'];
```

And APP_URL is used throughout the HTML templates. The problem is - the config needs to be as universal as possible, so there's less to do when switching environments.

Now, it works like this when I have configured a virtual host for my project, but when it isn't a virtual host, but sort of a localhost/myproject/ - the $config['SUBFOLDER'] has to be set manually to /myproject/

How do I do this programmatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set a variable in, for example, your htaccess file.

```
#.htccess
SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV development
```

then in your website do a check for this:

```
<?php
//live
$config['SUBFOLDER'] = '/';
//on localhost - override live settings
if(APPLICATION_ENV === 'development')
{
  $config['SUBFOLDER'] = '/myproject';
}
```

With this approach you only need to change one variable in the htaccess file.

If you just want to check if you are running on localhost, doing a check on `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` will also work:

```
<?php
if($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] === 'localhost')
{
  $config['SUBFOLDER'] = '/myproject';
}
```

Comment: I tried checking if HTTP_HOST is localhost, but then how do I pick up the value after localhost, that is /myproject/, programmatically? I tried using $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] but that only works for the index page.

Comment: if you are browsing to http://localhost/myproject/some-page.html, then `echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];` should show /myproject/some-page.html. Try `$parts = explode('/',$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); echo $parts[1];`. You should get 'myproject'.

Answer (score 0):

Check the URL whether it contains LOCALHOST or a normal domain name and wrap your config up in a conditional dependent on what the URL is.

Answer (score 0):

I take a slightly different approach..

```
if ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == 'testingserver') // local environment here
{
    // local settings
}
else if ( // remote environment here
    $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == 'www.something.com' ||
    $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == 'something.com'
) 
{
    // remote settings
}
else // error.. this shouldn't happen
{
    echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']; 
}
```